# Transfer contacts with multiple numbers from Android to Windows Phone

Tags: contacts, windows, data-transfer

I have transferred all contacts from the Android phone (Moto G) to the Windows Phone (Microsoft Lumia 540). I have multiple numbers for each contact in Android, but I can see only one number for a contact in my Windows phone.

For example, Sachine has two numbers: 999-999-9992 and 888-888-882.
In Windows, it shows Sachine: 999-999-9992 only.

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: How did you trasfer or which tool have you used to backup/transfer them to you Windows PC.? Did you export them as .vcf format?

Comment: I took the .csv file from google contact and import this .csv file to my windows (outlook) account. Through which i can see my contact in windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're transfering contacts just to back them up, you could try adding your contacts to your Google account, where they are automatically backed up, and you can also view them online, on [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com)

Comment: yes. it is back up in the google account. but i want to transfer all my contact to windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export them in vCard format (instead of CSV) from [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts) and import them into your Windows Phone.

If that doesn't work, then try to export contacts from your Contacts -> Export. This will be saved as `.vcf` file on your SD card. Transfer the file (via Bluetooth) and import this `.vcf` file into your Windows Phone.